# 'CookieAuthenticationProvider' does not contain a definition for 'SlidingExpiration. Claims expiration time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, startup, claims-based-identity

So, I was trying to set expiration time on claims in mvc. That is the code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Main/LogIn"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5),
                SlidingExpiration = true
            }

        });
    }
}
```

And both, `ExpireTimeSpan` and `SlidingExpiration` are underlined with red saying that:`'CookieAuthenticationProvider' does not contain a definition for 'SlidingExpiration/ExpireTimeSpan'`. Claims expiration time.

I'm new to it and was wondering what am I doing wrong here or what should I do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They belong to `CookieAuthenticationOptions` instead of the provider. That should resolve it.
 [CookieAuthenticationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Main/LogIn"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider(), 
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5),
        SlidingExpiration = true          

    });
```